# How to count posts using WP_Query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The following code has problems with the "if clause".

"Echo" displays the correct number "3", but "if count" displays "FOUND one" which is wrong.

It's supposed to display "FOUND a lot" since count number is 3.

I tried:

```php
$count_post = $about_preview_query->found_posts;

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

but still "if clause" shows one.

Would you please let me know how to fix the code?

```php
function profile_url(){
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if (!$user->ID) {
    return;
  }

  $args = array(
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'project',
    'post_status'    => 'publish'
  );

  $about_preview_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $count_post = $about_preview_query->post_count;

  if (count($count_post) == 0) {
    print "<h1>FOUND None</h1>";
  } elseif (count($count_post) == 1) {
    print "<h1>FOUND one</h1>";
  } else {
    print "<h1>FOUND a lot</h1>";
  }
  echo 'Your Count is: ' . $count_post;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: whats inside `$count_post`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct answer but the custom post has title, author and five acf fields

Comment: Please don't use Word to formulate questions/code

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
function profile_url() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( !$user->ID ){
        return;
    }    

    $args = array(
        'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'project',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );
    
    $about_preview_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $count_post = $about_preview_query->found_posts;

    if ( $count_post == 0 ) {
        print "<h1>FOUND None</h1>"; } 
    elseif ( $count_post == 1 ) { 
        print "<h1>FOUND one</h1>";
    }else {
        print "<h1>FOUND a lot</h1>";
    }

    echo 'Your Count is: ' . $count_post; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Binh : ) I didn't know how to write if caluse and I learnt it from you.